# Automatic choice of curly and straight extensible braces in MTPro2

Tags: mtpro

The MTProII fonts provide two sets of curly braces, the straight extensible ones and the curly desinged braces that extend up to 4in high.... and that is all very dandy, except that when using the `{cases}` construct from the `amsmath` it (automatically) sometimes chooses one type and sometimes choose another in a mix that does not look very nice:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mtpro2}
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{cases}
a_n=2 a_{n-1}+1, \quad \forall\,n\geq 2,\\
a_1=1.\\
\end{cases}
\]

\[
\begin{cases}
a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2},\quad \forall\,n\geq 3,\\
a_1=1,\\
a_2=1,\\
\end{cases}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Is this an error in the package that loads the fonts or something that could be controlled from the outside?

I have been looking at the code, but cannot quite locate the place where this is controlled.

Is it possible to handle this differently by using `fontspec` and avoiding the package `mtpro2`?

I am aware of the question/answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195613/mtpro2-curly-braces-as-default), but that deal with a different problem -- not the automatic choice of `cases`.

Comment: isn't this just the usual thing that a font has so many designed size characters then switches to the straight extender, does the font really have a designed left brace that big? LaTeX doesn't control this at all it just uses `\left\{` and gets whatever the font supplies.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle definitely the font supplies both -- as you can see in the file above.

Comment: Ah OK I see egreg's answer that you link to. OK so that basically is the answer here too. The font switches to the straight form as you show but there are larger designed size ones available,

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I understand that I can choose them by hand -- no problem there, but the question is why amslatex is choosing one is or another depending on the size.

Comment: latex has no control over this, it just does `\left\{` and the font specifies what is returned. The designer of the mtpro fonts has (unusually) made some additional glyphs which are not in the chained sequence that makes up the variable sized delimiter. TeX has no access to the information at all.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I would like to understand better your statement "latex has no control over this, it just does `\left\{` and the font specifies what is returned". I am having a hard time believe it. What mechanism a font has to recognize what is `\left\{` and specify what is used? One of the character (above) is NOT even in the font, how can it choose to return it?

Comment: the complete definition of `\lbrace` is  `\DeclareMathDelimiter{\lbrace}{\mathopen}{symbols}{"66}{largesymbols}{"08}` which is a latex macro equivalent to the primitive definition in plain tex `\def\lbrace{\delimiter"4266308 }` so all tex knows is a normal { is character hex 66 from math family 4 and if you use `\left` and need something bigger then use the character 8 from math family 3.  How or if the cmex font that is family 3 specifies how to construct a larger brace is in the font metrics and not accessible to tex macros

Answer (score 4):

First the output (code below):

[image: cases]

### Short answer

Use the patch [`mtpro2-patch.tex`](https://github.com/RuixiZhang42/font-pairing-guide/blob/master/mtpro2-patch.tex) I developed over the years (my “shameless plug”).

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mtpro2}

\input{mtpro2-patch}% https://github.com/RuixiZhang42/font-pairing-guide/blob/master/mtpro2-patch.tex

\begin{document}
Every \verb|cases| uses curly brace:
\[
\begin{cases}
a_n=2 a_{n-1}+1, \quad \forall\,n\geq 2,\\
a_1=1.\\
\end{cases}
\qquad
\begin{cases}
a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2},\quad \forall\,n\geq 3,\\
a_1=1,\\
a_2=1,\\
\end{cases}
\]

\straightbraces
Now, every \verb|cases| uses straight brace:
\[
\begin{cases}
a_n=2 a_{n-1}+1, \quad \forall\,n\geq 2,\\
a_1=1.\\
\end{cases}
\qquad
\begin{cases}
a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2},\quad \forall\,n\geq 3,\\
a_1=1,\\
a_2=1,\\
\end{cases}
\]

\end{document}
```

### Long answer

The following provides essentially a brief documentation for one small part of `mtpro2-patch.tex`.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mtpro2}

\makeatletter
% First, we need a test to see which braces are in force.
% The mtpro2 package provides 3 sets of braces. We treat
% curly braces as one type, while morphed and straight
% braces as another type.
\expandafter\def\csname mtp2@lcbrace\endcsname
  {\delimiter"4266308 }% define our own left curly brace
\newcommand*\@ifcurlybraces{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname mtp2@lcbrace\endcsname\lbrace
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
% Next, we redefine the cases environment.
% If curly braces are in force, we use the \LEFTRIGHT construction.
% Otherwise, we use the \left...\right construction.
\newsavebox\mtp@matrix@cases
\renewenvironment{cases}{%
  \matrix@check\cases
  \setbox\mtp@matrix@cases\hbox\bgroup$%
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \def\arraystretch{1.1}% less than 1000/\delimiterfactor, my personal preference
  \array{@{}l@{\quad}l@{}}%
}{%
  \endarray
  \m@th$\egroup
  \@ifcurlybraces{%
    \LEFTRIGHT@\lbrace.{\,\copy\mtp@matrix@cases}%
  }{%
    \left\lbrace\copy\mtp@matrix@cases\right.%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Every \verb|cases| uses curly brace:
\[
\begin{cases}
a_n=2 a_{n-1}+1, \quad \forall\,n\geq 2,\\
a_1=1.\\
\end{cases}
\qquad
\begin{cases}
a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2},\quad \forall\,n\geq 3,\\
a_1=1,\\
a_2=1,\\
\end{cases}
\]

\straightbraces
Now, every \verb|cases| uses straight brace:
\[
\begin{cases}
a_n=2 a_{n-1}+1, \quad \forall\,n\geq 2,\\
a_1=1.\\
\end{cases}
\qquad
\begin{cases}
a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2},\quad \forall\,n\geq 3,\\
a_1=1,\\
a_2=1,\\
\end{cases}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there and English page for the patch? Going to https://github.com/RuixiZhang42/font-pairing-guide has an English call, but clicking on it leads to a 404.

Comment: @PauloNey Sorry, you can blame that on my procrastination and laziness… That repo is severely under-documented, but the patch file itself contains comments written in English. If you are not comfortable inputting the entire patch file, you can use the code in my long answer to get the desired result. The entire patch file contains fixes for other bugs in `amsmath` and LaTeX kernel (some of these bugs are not officially recognized by the kernel team, and may never get fixed for backward compatibility reasons), so the patch file can change your old documents.

Comment: @PauloNey I have updated `README-EN.md`. Feel free to give my patch file a try :)

Comment: This is great and fixed my issue. Thanks!